# How to get Complex object with EFcore using foreign key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using asp net core 5 for developing web API!
I have a problem that i create my database with EFCORE and I want to query an object that has foreign key!

Here is my code:

```
public long RefreshTokenId { get; set; }
public string JwtTokenId { get; set;}
public User user { get; set; }
public Int64 expirationTime { get; set; }
public string Token { get; set; }
public bool Revoked { get; set; }
```

In this class I use User Object as an object with foreign key in one to one relation according to efcore documentation!

Here is my problem:

```
public async Task<long> RefreshToken(RefreshRequest refreshRequest)
{
RefreshToken refreshToken = await Task.Run(() => {
    return _appContext.refreshTokens.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Token ==  
         refreshRequest.refreshToken);
});

 return refreshToken.user.UserId;
 }
```

When I run this function the null pointer exception is thrown!
Can anybody explain me how to retrieve user object with efcore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main issue is that i wanted to load related data with foreign key and it has three methods and the following links would help you!

[from MicroSoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)
[from tutorials in internnt!](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/explicit-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 public async Task<long> RefreshToken(RefreshRequest refreshRequest)
        {
        RefreshToken refreshToken = await Task.Run(() => {
            return _appContext.refreshTokens.Where(x => x.Token ==  
                 refreshRequest.refreshToken).SingleOrDefault();
        });

         return refreshToken.user.UserId;
         }
```